Is there an evaluation metric for (time series) regression that evaluates how accurate the shape of the "curve" is?
I am trying to predict a value y. I am mainly interested in when its peaks are and how the general curve for a day will look. It's less important the actualy predicted values are correct.
A bit exaggerated: I don't care if every predicted value is 10 times as big as the actual value, as long as every single predicted value is 10 times as high. In addition to that, peaks are way more important in my case than lows or averages, which means errors close to peak values should be penalized higher.
I know about the standard evaluation metrics like RSME, MAE, etc. However, unless I missunderstood them, they all try to meassure a sort of "average" or "mean" error, which is not necessarily what I am interested in.
I searched for it, but maybe also due to my lack to express my problem well enough in a search engine, I didn't find anything really.
Feel free to ask if I didn't clarify sth.

There is the possibility that you're actually misunderstanding the term "average" here though. Your correct in pointing out "average error" but maybe it's not 100% clear on what this means. Visualize a curve and your prediction. If your "average error" is good that means that over the whole curve your prediction is on average not that far off.
If this is understood then it sounds a bit like you're trying to have both the average (because that gives you the measure of "does the curve fit generally") but also want to make sure peaks are weighted more.
For the second point you can use accuracy metrics like a peak weighted MAPE or similar that actually weight errors close to those peaks more than others. Another way would be to penalize peaks more (like doing an mean error but with higher orders of exponents).
In real life problems I would use both and report on "peak" error as well as general fit

@Phillip Thanks for the reply. The weighted MAPE sounds good, even tho my y value is between 0 and 1, which (from my short search) would penalize "low/non-peak" erros higher. but maybe I can inverse the y_true/y_prediction before applying the metric, I'll see.
About the first thing, I did want the shape of the curve to fit. lets say, you remove the y axis. if you "move" the curve up and down, it still is absolutely fine, as the shape of the curve stays the same. However, after reading your reply and thinking about it, I think RSME & weighted MAPE sound good enough for my case!

I can't add comments to you question, for trying to clarify my understanding.
So here, maybe helping me might help you as well. It seems to me that you may be looking for qualitative invariants perhaps about the weekly time series of the time derivative estimate, that this derived time series would be more informative than the source time series Y variable.
Not having read further to dismiss the above hypothesis of my reading, I would think you might want to look into time window based estimation tools, or some kind of kernel integration of your time series (I would not know how to name that).  now reading further.  The derivative is about the slope we you seem to find more informative than where is the variable at some time point.
The slope, depending on your estimator range, and time series time grain of sampliong, would be possibly classifyable in some bins of your interest.
This vague answer might count or serve to help in refining your question.
Ok re-read. And it seems you want some day averaging of that derive quantity. If I made sense at all.  Well, that might be depending on how you build the derivative estimator.  My words might not be words or terms of art in statistics or your background. I would not know the acronyms.
